# Trying to calculate the amount of tax someone needs to pay based on age

Tags: python, datetime, if-statement, while-loop, break

This is my current code, and I'm trying to calculate the amount of tax someone needs to pay based on their age. The calculations are right, but I keep getting errors.

```
    #Get the Age of from user input
    from datetime import datetime, date
    
    print("Please enter your date of birth (dd mm yyyy)")
    date_of_birth = datetime.strptime(input("--->"), "%d %m %Y")
    
    def calculate_age(born):
        today = date.today()
        return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))
    
    age = calculate_age(date_of_birth)
    
    print("You are " ,int(age), " years old.")
    
    #Get the Salary from user input
    def get_salary():
        while True:
            try:
                salary = int(input("Please enter your salary: "))
            except ValueError:
                print("You need to enter a number ")
            else:
                break
        return salary
    
    #Calculate the Amount that needs to be paid, using if,elif,else
    def contribution(age):
        if age <= 35:
            tax = (salary * 0.20)
        elif 36 <= age <= 50:
            tax = (salary * 0.20)
        elif 51 <= age <= 55:
            tax = (salary * 0.185)
        elif 56 <= age <= 60:
            tax = (salary * 0.13)
        elif 61 <= age <= 65:
            tax = (salary * 0.075)
        else:
            tax = (salary * 0.05)
    
        return tax
    
    #Print the amount 
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        salary = get_salary
        tax = contribution(age)
        print("you have to pay", tax, " every month.")
```

This is the error that keeps popping up:

```
Please enter your date of birth (dd mm yyyy)
--->01 08 1946
You are  74  years old.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/mikael/Age-TaxCalculator.py", line 46, in <module>
    tax = contribution(age)
  File "/Users/mikael/Age-TaxCalculator.py", line 39, in contribution
    tax = (salary * 0.05)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'function' and 'float'
>>>
```

When the program ends, I would like it to prompt the user if he/she needs to do another calculation. After researching for hours trying to find a solution, do I move the whole main code into this function?

```
while True:
    #input the whole code
    while True:
        answer = str(input("Do you need to do another calculation? (y/n): "))
        if answer in ("y", "n"):
            break
        print "invalid input."
    if answer == "y":
        continue
    else:
        print("Thank you, Goodbye")
        break
```

Comment: shouldn't salary = get_salary be --> salary = get_salary()

Comment: Oh my... it works. Okay, but I still can't get it to restart from the top. Any clues as to how I should go about it?

Comment: see my posted answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
#Get the Age of from user input
from datetime import datetime, date

#define functions before main script
def calculate_age(born):
    today = date.today()
    return today.year - born.year - ((today.month, today.day) < (born.month, born.day))

#Calculate the Amount that needs to be paid, using if,elif,else
def contribution(age):
    if age <= 35:
        tax = (salary * 0.20)
    elif 36 <= age <= 50:
        tax = (salary * 0.20)
    elif 51 <= age <= 55:
        tax = (salary * 0.185)
    elif 56 <= age <= 60:
        tax = (salary * 0.13)
    elif 61 <= age <= 65:
        tax = (salary * 0.075)
    else:
        tax = (salary * 0.05)

    return tax

#run until close = True
close = False
while close = False:
    print("Please enter your date of birth (dd mm yyyy)") #get age input
    date_of_birth = datetime.strptime(input("--->"), "%d %m %Y")

    age = calculate_age(date_of_birth) #get age from function calculate_age()

    print("You are " ,int(age), " years old.")

    #Get the Salary from user input
    while not salary.is_integer(): #keep asking for salary until it is an int
        salary = int(input("Please enter your salary: "))
        if not salary.is_integer(): #if the salary inputed is an int it will skip this next step
            print("You need to enter a number!")
    
    salary = get_salary() #get salary from get_salary()
    tax = contribution(age) #calculate the tax
    print("you have to pay", tax, " every month.")

    ask = input("Do you need another calculation?") #if ask is yes close will stay as false and the script will just run again
    if ask == 'yes' or ask == 'y':
        return
    elif ask == 'no' or ask == 'n': #if ask is no, close will be set to True closing the script
        close = True
```

Comment: Thanks, also I was wondering if I could use data structures instead of straight calculating the tax. Thank you so much